# Rails, how to display jquery-ui-datepicker calender on specific page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have already jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5) version and displayed calender as below,

[image]

this calender is displayed in all pages,

i need to display different calender as below,

[image]

on specific page.

```
    $("#new_calender").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    language: "en",
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    todayHighlight: true,
    toggleActive: true,
    autoclose: true
    });
```

Comment: Check various options for customization [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate). Do you just want to set a different default on different pages ?

Comment: How can I change langauge of datepicker, i have tried like `language: ja,`  it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the jQuery UI datepicker localization files available at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n are included. They may already be inculded by the `jquery-ui-rails` gem so check that too.

You can override an individual datepicker for a specific locale:

`$("#new_calender").datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ja" ] );`

Do this after intializing the datepicker, I dont see a `language` option in the jQuery UI options for datepicker so dont think thats the right way.